# Stripe CLI Payment Intent Connect

Tags: stripe-payments

Can anyone tell me the syntax for Stripe CLI application fees keep getting this error

"Can only apply an application fee when the request is made on behalf of another account (using an OAuth key, the Stripe-Account header, or the destination parameter)"

I cant decipher the destination parameter syntax e.g

stripe payment_intents create --amount 2000 --application-fee-amount 500  --customer cus_testuser --currency=eur --payment-method pm_card_visa --confirm=true -d transfer_data[]=acct_test user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a destination charge with an application fee through the Stripe CLI like this:

```
stripe payment_intents create --amount 2000 --application-fee-amount 500 --customer cus_testuser --currency=eur --payment-method pm_card_visa --confirm=true -d transfer_data[destination]=acct_xxx
```

Note: The change is the "destination" between brackets.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66983230/9409877